# How to use common directive for lazy load modules in angular 8

Tags: typescript, angular7, angular8

I have created one directive for numbers only type.I have imported that in root app module but i am not able to use in lazy modules.How to resolve this issue?

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pctddo-1pyfzu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

app.module.ts:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NumberDirective } from './numbers-only.directive';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NumberDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
 export class AppModule { }
```

customer-list.component.html

```
<input type="text" numbersOnly placeholder="Numbers only">
```

order-list.component.html

```
<input type="text" numbersOnly placeholder="Numbers only">
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'customers',
    loadChildren: './customers/customers.module#CustomersModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'orders',
    loadChildren: './orders/orders.module#OrdersModule'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an ui-module for it. By this way, you can import `DirectivesModule` which module you want to use it.

Another way is that you can use `AppModule` or `SharedModule` if your directives are very common.

I updated your [Stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pctddo-unqnoq)

*directives.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [NumberDirective],
  exports: [NumberDirective]
})

export class DirectivesModule {}
```

**Why you need to export your directives from DirectivesModule?**

> If you don't export your directives, your application registers
>   directives only and only inside your `DirectivesModule`

Lastly, you need to import it at your lazy module.

*lazy.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    DirectivesModule
  ],
  declarations: [...]
})
export class LazyModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `feature module` for the directive and import it in appropriate module whenever you are going to use it because all entities (components, directives, pipes) declared in `declarations` array belong only to this module.

*Also, don't forget to export the directive from the module*

---

[The declarations array](https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping#the-declarations-array)

[Feature modules](https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules)

Comment: How to create feature module? Can you update my stackblitz?

Comment: I think feature module already there.please check app-routing.module.ts

Comment: Not working - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pctddo-cy2hgu?file=src/app/app.module.ts